# Divergence theorem proof , vector calculus

Tags: vector-analysis, orthogonality, divergence-operator, curl

[image]

im completely stuck on this , i am full unable to do the second question even though i know its related to the curl

for the first one i got only up to and i dont know where to go from here [image]

Comment: use the first and fifth identities and $$  \nabla (e^f)  = (e^f)  \nabla f $$

Comment: how would the fifth identity give me the answer u got

Comment: oh you mean the fifth identity for question 2 , i thought you were talking about question 1

Comment: You have question 1 correct, all you need to do there is to plug in the equation I wrote in my first comment.